# Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'addCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, compiler-errors

I am new to AngularJS and facing this error,I took help from all Stackoverflow reference for same error but failed to solve my issue so posting here.The code was working fine and as soon as I integrated plivo modules it has started giving following error.[image]

Please help me to solve this issue,already wasted 1 day.Thanks.

**addCtrl.js**

```
// Creates the addCtrl Module and Controller. Note that it depends on 'geolocation' and 'gservice' modules.
var addCtrl = angular.module('addCtrl', ['angularModalService']);
addCtrl.controller('addCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $location,$routeParams, $q , $timeout , plivoclient, ModalService){

    // Initializes Variables
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.formData.preferredMode = "data";
    $scope.formData.emailId = "prateek@teledna.com";
    $scope.formData.phone = "+919986040933";

    $scope.$on('incoming:call', function(event, data) {
            console.log('Instance Id: ' + data.extraHeaders['X-Ph-Instid']);
            $timeout(function() {
                ModalService.showModal({
                    templateUrl: 'partials/addForm.html',
                    controllerAs: 'vm',
                    controller: 'IncomingCallController',
                    inputs: {
                        from: data.callerName || '',
                        instId: data.extraHeaders['X-Ph-Instid'] || data.extraHeaders['X-Ph-instid']
                    }
                });
            }, 0);
        });


    function activate(){
        console.log("activate in addCtrl is called..");
        callResolver();
    }

    activate();

    var param1 = $routeParams.param1;
    var param2 = $routeParams.param2;

    console.log(param1);
    console.log(param2);

    // submitting new user Details
    $scope.submitUserDetails = function() {

        var userData = {
            emailId: $scope.formData.emailId,
            preferredMode: $scope.formData.preferredMode,
            phone: $scope.formData.phone,
            alternatePhone: $scope.formData.alternatePhone,
        };

        console.log('in normal add user :'+JSON.stringify(userData));

        // Saves the user data to the db
        saveUserData(userData);
    };


    function saveUserData(userData){
        $http.post('/users', userData)
            .success(function (data) {
                $location.path('/submitted');
            })
            .error(function (data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            });
    }

    function callResolver() {
        console.log("call resolver is called..");
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var sessionUser= {
                "plivo_sip_credentials": {
                    "username": "N919986040933160719091504",
                    "password": "now1516confer",
                    "endpoint_id": "95086867054112",
                    "sip_uri": "sip:N919986040933160719091504@phone.plivo.com"
                }
            };
            plivoclient.start(sessionUser).then(function() {
                console.log("Plivo client connected..");
                deferred.resolve();
            }, function() {
                 console.log("Plivo client cannot be connected..");
                deferred.reject(4);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        };

});
```

**app.js**

```
// Declares the initial angular module "NowConfer". Module grabs other controllers and services.
var app = angular.module('nowconfer', ['ngRoute' , 'addCtrl'])

    // Configures Angular routing -- showing the relevant view and controller when needed.
    .config(function($routeProvider){

        // Join Team Control Panel
        $routeProvider.when('/join/:param1/:param2', {
            controller: 'addCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'partials/addForm.html',

        // Find Teammates Control Panel
        }).
        when('/submitted', {
            template: '<div>Thankyou for choosing the preferred mode of call.</div>',
        // Find Teammates Control Panel
        }).otherwise({redirectTo:'/join'})
    });
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- Declares NowConfer as the starting Angular module -->
<html class="no-js" ng-app="nowconfer">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NowConfer</title>
    <meta name="description" content="NowConfer">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

    <!-- JS Source -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-modal-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/plivosdk/web/beta-rc2/plivo.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Files -->


    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plivoservice.js"></script>
    <script src="js/addCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/inject-plivo-directive.js"></script>
    <script src="js/incoming.controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/callresolver.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Header Menu. Note use of headerCtrl -->
    <div class="header" ng-controller="addCtrl">

        <!-- Header items are made active upon selection -->
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
             <li ><a href="/#/join">Prateek</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Header Title -->
        <h3 class="text-muted"><img src="images/l_nowconfer_logo.png" alt="NowConfer" /></h3>
    </div>

    <!-- Map and Side Panel -->
    <div class="row content">

        <div ng-view></div>

    </div>
    <hr/>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="footer">
        <p class="text-center"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Design & developed by <a href="#">ComVerg Technologies Pvt. Ltd.</a></p>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**incoming.controller.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('nowconfer',['ngRoute'])
        .controller('IncomingCallController', IncomingCallController);

    IncomingCallController.$inject = ['$rootScope','plivoclient','$routeProvider','$location'];

    function IncomingCallController($rootScope , plivoclient,$routeProvider ,$location) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.from = from;
        vm.connecting = false;

        vm.accept = function() {
            plivoclient.conn.answer();
            vm.connecting = true;
            console.log("incoming call accept");
        };

        vm.hangUp = function() {
            plivoclient.conn.reject();
            console.log("incoming call hangedup");
        };

        $rootScope.$on('incoming:call:answered', function() {
            console.log("incoming call answered");
            $location.path('/join/1/2');
        });

        $rootScope.$on('incoming:call:cancelled', function() {
            console.log("incoming call cancelled");
        });
    }

}());
```

**callresolver.js**

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('nowconfer')
        .factory('callResolver', callResolver);

    callResolver.$inject = ['$q','plivoclient'];

    function callResolver($q, plivoclient) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
         var sessionUser= {
                "plivo_sip_credentials": {
                "username": "N919986040933160719091504",
                "password": "now1516confer",
                "endpoint_id": "95086867054112",
                "sip_uri": "sip:N919986040933160719091504@phone.plivo.com"
            }
            };
        plivoclient.start(sessionUser);
        deferred.resolve();
        return deferred.promise;
    };

})();
```

Comment: Read read these line `var addCtrl = angular.module('addCtrl', ['angularModalService']);
addCtrl.controller('addCtrl')` You are defining `addCtrl` as a module then as a controller

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the module name from `addCtrl` to `addCtrlModule` or something. I think the module name is conflicting with controller name.

Just try changing this line of code in `addCtrl.js` to following.

```
var addCtrl = angular.module('addCtrlModule', ['angularModalService']);
```

and in `app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('nowconfer', ['ngRoute' , 'addCtrlModule'])
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry,still not working,is there problem in order of scripts

Comment: Try changing the order put `<script src="lib/angular-modal-service.js"></script>` down after `callresolver.js`

Comment: @Pratswinz any success??

Comment: i will post new code,did lots of changes and converted all methods to IIFE

Answer (score 0):

Module and controller naming is not problem
[check this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wzzJYx). Propably problem is in order of loading scripts. I advice you to quickly read this [John Papa Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) to avoid future similar problems.

And code to prove that module name can be the same as controller name.

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular.module('addCtrl', [])
  .controller('addCtrl', ctrl);

  function ctrl(){
    this.test = 'Hello';
  }

  angular.module('nowconfer', ['addCtrl']);
})();
```

Comment: sorry,It did not help

Comment: Try to refactor your code. Wrap your modules in IIFE. Check again order of scripts in html. In your html app.js is above addCtrl.js. app.js should be last loaded script.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you do not need to create a module for your controller as it is not an injectable controller. you can do

```
angular.module('nowconfer').controller('addCtrl', function(){
       .......
})
```

Second, if you are creating a module and injecting in your app config then make sure that its dependency has already been loaded. so load your module before app.js .

Hope this helps!!